# I want to merge two object either in an array or prior to saving

Tags: iphone, nsarray, nsobject, abpeoplepickerview

I am saving the first and last name from ABpeoplepickerNavcontroller, I would like to merge the first and last name prior to saving into an array so that when i retrieve it, they would be together. The first code is the object being created:

```
// setting the first name
firstName.text = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

// setting the last name
lastName.text = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
```

Here's where I save it:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:firstName.text];
[array addObject:lastName.text];
[array addObject:addressLabel.text];

[array writeToFile:recipient atomically:NO];
[array release];
```

Can I save add two objects on one line? or Can I merge the objects prior to adding to array?

Thanks, and for the record...this site and the people who have helped me have been fantastic.

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Address Book Programming Guide for iPhone:

"However, in actual applications, the function ABRecordCopyCompositeName is the recommended way to get a person’s full name to display. It puts the first and last name in the order preferred by the user, which provides a more uniform user experience."

The solutions here will work but it's something you may not need to do at all if you just use the composite name.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, This was the best choice...I forgot about that compositename function. 5 weeks ago sounds is an eternity when remembering code. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you mean by merging. If you want to append one string to the other do the following:

```
NSString *joinedNamed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName.text, lastName.text];
```

Comment: Thanks also , I used the CompositeName

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `stringByAppendingString` like this:

`[array addObject:[firstName.text stringByAppendingString:lastName.text]]`;

Comment: Thanks, the Compositename was a better fit.